# How can I login to a host for which I have to SSH twice through a Java application i.e. first to one host then from that to other host?

Tags: java, ssh, openshift, jsch

There are 2 hosts. First I have to SSH to the first host and then after that I have to SSH on that host to finally reach the host I wish to connect to.

Basically I need to do this to access my OpenShift host.

I tried using the JSCH library and I am able to SSH to the first host. 
I am also able to SSH to the second host, however once on the 2nd host I am unable to run any commands on it and it just continues in an infinite loop.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Don't do that. Use a tunnel. On the commandline you should be using `ProxyCommand` - this is 2016 not 1970. With JSCH you can use `setProxy`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567031/how-to-use-jsch-with-proxycommands-for-portforwarding) - was going to dup, but that question has no good answers.